# Can Gale Blast be heightened?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

[Gale Blast](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=917) from Secrets of Magic is the only damaging cantrip that cannot be Heightened.
Is this a typo?

Comment: Questions about rule intent are off topic, so I would recommend rephrasing this to not ask about rule intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the book (Secrets of Magic), on page 108, there is the missing part:

> Heightened (+2) The damage increases by 1d6

So the problem only exists online.

Comment: FWIW, I have now sent them an email pointing out this error

Comment: @Medix2, they fixed it